# PHP - Find the number of groups given some constraints

Tags: php, logic

Given n = 3 dogs and m = 3 pairs of enemies, a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [3, 3, 1], dog 1 is the enemy of dog 3, and dog 3 is the enemy of dogs 1 and 2. Because 3 is an enemy of both 1 and 2, it must be in its own container. dogs 1 and 2 can be together or separately. There are 4 possible groups: {1, 2} ,{1}, {2}, {3}. Note that the intervals are along the original line of dogs numbered consecutively from 1 to n, i.e. [1, 2, 3] in this case. The dogs cannot be reordered and dogs cannot be skipped, e.g. {2, 1} and {1, 3} are invalid.

So given the following:

**case #1**:

```
n = 5
m = 2
a = (1,2)
b = (3,5)
```

Result is: Total of 11 groups can be formed.

**case #2**

```
n = 8
m = 4
a = (2,3,4,3)
b = (8,5,6,4)
```

Result is: Total of 18 groups can be formed.

---

Here's my code:

```
function countSubstrings($n, $a, $b) {
    $tokenArr = array(); 
    $x = 1;
    while ($x <= $n){
        $tokenArr[] = $x;
        $x++;
    }

    $first = 0;
    $last = $n - 1;
    $outArr   = array();
    $pointer  = 0;

    /* generate groups left to right */
    for ($i = $first; $i <= $last; $i++) {
        $outArr[$pointer][] = $tokenArr[$i];
        $tokenString = $tokenArr[$i];
        $pointer++; 
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j <= $last; $j++) {
            $tokenString .= $tokenArr[$j];
            $outArr[$pointer] = str_split($tokenString);
            $pointer++;
        }
    }

    /* find the enemeies */
    $intersects = array();
    for($k = 0; $k < count($outArr); $k++){
        if (count(array_intersect($outArr[$k], $a)) > 1 || count(array_intersect($outArr[$k], $b)) > 1) {
            $intersects[] = $outArr[$k];
        }
    }

    /* remove first and last items which are basically equal to $a and $b */
    $intersects = array_slice($intersects, 1, -1); 


    /* remove the enemeies from generated groups */
    foreach ($outArr as $keya => $valuea) {
        if (in_array($valuea, $intersects)) {
            unset($outArr[$keya]);
        }
    }

    return count($outArr);
}
```

So far my code works in case: #1 but fails on #2.

Comment: Good try. The intersect logic seems to be incorrect to me as we have to check if the relationship formed by `[a , b]`, for example, `[1,2]` exists in `$outArr` or not. Current check of `count(array_intersect($outArr[$k], $a)) > 1` does not care about that. It rather checks if any element in `$a` is present in `$outArr[$k]` or not.

Comment: It's not about array_intersect, but rather about the way of checking. Anyways, I have added an answer.

Comment: I think we could further optimize this. I will notify when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersect logic seems to be incorrect to me as we have to check if the relationship formed by `[a , b]`, for example, `[1,2]` exists in `$outArr` or not. Current check of `count(array_intersect($outArr[$k], $a)) > 1` does not care about that. It rather checks if any element in `$outArr[$k]` is present in `$a` or not.

So, change the current logic from:

```
/* find the enemeies */
    $intersects = array();
    for($k = 0; $k < count($outArr); $k++){
        if (count(array_intersect($outArr[$k], $a)) > 1 || count(array_intersect($outArr[$k], $b)) > 1) {
            $intersects[] = $outArr[$k];
        }
    }

    /* remove first and last items which are basically equal to $a and $b */
    $intersects = array_slice($intersects, 1, -1);
```

to

```
$intersects = array();
foreach($a as $index => $val1){
    $val2 = $b[$index];
    foreach($outArr as $current_group){
        if(in_array($val1,$current_group) && in_array($val2,$current_group)){ // check if both exist as they are enemies
            $intersects[] = $current_group;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Q2rnP

In the above code, we:

- loop through all elements of `$a` and simultaneously with `$b` with the help of `$index` in foreach.
- Check if for the current group in `$outArr`, whether both `$a[$index]`(a.k.a `$val1`) and `$b[$index]`(a.k.a `$val2`) exist in the group or not.
- If both exist in current group, we put them under intersect as they are enemies. Your rest of the logic is correct.

---

**Efficient Solution:**

- We have to exploit this line:

> A group is defined as an interval (x, y) such that all dogs in the range from x to y form a group.

- This means that we need to look at subarrays(as you correctly judged) instead of subsequences.
- Now, we loop from `1` to `N` and if we find a number which has an enemy on the left, we can only form the next groups from that number + 1 onwards. Anything before them can't be included anyway since we are looking at subarrays.
- For example, let's assume `5` is an enemy of `3` in a line of `1` to `5` and no other enemies are present. So, group formations would look like below.

**Representation:**

```
  1   2   3   4   5 
 -1  -1   5  -1   3

  |___|
  |___|___|
  |___|___|___|
      |___|
      |___|___|
          |___|


              |___| // the connection/group (4,5) remains and breaks everything before 4 since 3 is an enemy of 5 and we are looking for subarrays. So everything before 4 is disconnected anyway.
```

- So, our next starting animal/dog to look from is `4`.
- For each enemy/animal, we maintain the nearest enemy on the left if present. If present, we update the next animal to look from for groups as proved above. In the below code, `$prev_start` is the variable that maintains the next animal to look from.
- In order to get nearest enemy on the left for each animal, we preprocess the enemy details as follows:

**Preprocessing:**

```
$enemies = array_combine(range(1,$n),array_fill(0,$n,-1)); // nothing tricky, just generates an array filled with sequential numbers as keys and sets it's value as -1

   foreach($a as $index => $enemy_1){
      $enemy_2 = $b[$index]; 
      if($enemy_1 < $enemy_2){
        $enemies[$enemy_2] = max($enemies[$enemy_2],$enemy_1);
      }else if($enemy_2 < $enemy_1){
        $enemies[$enemy_1] = max($enemies[$enemy_1],$enemy_2);   
      }
   }
```

**Computation:**

```
   $prev_start = 1;
   $count = 0; 

   for($i=1;$i<=$n;++$i){
     if($enemies[$i] !== -1){
         $prev_start = max($enemies[$i] + 1,$prev_start);
     }

     $count += ($i - $prev_start + 1);
   }
```

- Since we preprocessed enemy details, we update `$prev_start` accordingly from where we have to start counting for groups again.
- `$count += ($i - $prev_start + 1);` simply counts the number of groups(subarrays) to consider for counting.
- **Time complexity:** `O(m + n)` where `m` is number of pairs and `n` is the number of dogs/animals.
- **Space complexity:** `O(n)` where `n` is the number of dogs/animals.

**Full Code:**

```
<?php

function countSubarrays($n, $a, $b) {
   $enemies = array_combine(range(1,$n),array_fill(0,$n,-1)); // nothing tricky, just generates an array filled with sequential numbers as keys and sets it's value as -1

   foreach($a as $index => $enemy_1){
      $enemy_2 = $b[$index]; 
      if($enemy_1 < $enemy_2){
        $enemies[$enemy_2] = max($enemies[$enemy_2],$enemy_1);
      }else if($enemy_2 < $enemy_1){
        $enemies[$enemy_1] = max($enemies[$enemy_1],$enemy_2);   
      }
   }

   $prev_start = 1;
   $count = 0; 

  for($i=1;$i<=$n;++$i){
     if($enemies[$i] !== -1){
         $prev_start = max($enemies[$i] + 1,$prev_start);
     }

     $count += ($i - $prev_start + 1);
  }

   return $count;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/1W26C

Comment: @Carl I am trying for the optimized one and your question says  `m = some x pairs of enemies`, so `$a` having `(1,2,3,4,5)` and `$b` having `(1,3,5)` doesn't make sense. These form a pair at each index. So there is no question about `count($a)` not being to equal to `count($b)`.

Comment: @Carl Yes, please update your question and it would be better to share the original document as is.

Comment: @Carl So it's a hackerrank challenge. Yes, `m` is going to remain same for both `a` and `b`, but looking at the constraints, a brute force wouldn't get accepted.

Comment: @Carl See if this solution passes https://3v4l.org/kh058 . I will add explanation once confirmed that it's correct.

Comment: @Carl Great. Added explanation :)